How much must I change a table to be clear of any copyright issues?
I am writing a chapter where I want to include a copyrighted table from a published article as an example of how some test analysis was performed and presented.
On one hand, the closer the table is to the original, the better the example it would make I figure, on the other, the editors and publisher have explicitly told us to avoid using copyrighted material as far as possible.
I am the original author of the table and it is trivial to copy-paste it in Latex form from the original manuscript to the chapter manuscript. So I wonder how much change is needed for it to be considered a "new", non-copyrighted, table?
Possible options include for instance: replacing actual data with dummy data, only including parts of it, changing background color, changing font, changing headings, or changing margins and width (no work for me since the chapter has different margins than the article).

Generally, the entries in the table (data) are not copyrightable, only the presentation of the table overall.

Who owns the copyright? What did you sign when you published the original work?  I would speak to the copyright holder (which may well be you!).  Also the press where the new chapter is published may have some rules.

If you don’t need the actual data (possible option to "replacing actual data with dummy data") nor the structure (… and "changing headings") why use that table at all?

@JonCuster That is my understanding, but replacing the data or removing parts of it could arguably change the presentation of the table.

@Elin The journal is the copyright holder, and while I can still reproduce the material for my own work, it does not include work that will be published by a publisher for instance, like these chapters.

@MisterMiyagi I want to use the table as it is an example of how the data has been analyzed and presented.

@JohanPI I would understand that if replacing the data and structure were not fine by you. Since it is, what exactly is left there that makes it a unique example?

In most places this would be a judgement call and subject to civil law. You could get sued. The changes you suggest are inessential to the information you are presenting in the figure. That is problematic, but up to the copyright holder to decide.
But it sounds like you are deliberately trying to circumvent copyright and that, in itself is problematic.
Suppose you take a #1 selling novel and republish it changing background color, font, headings, margins, and width. Does that sound appropriate? Safe? The things you suggest changing are not, in almost every case, the thing that makes the work copyrightable.
Moreover, since figures can contain a lot of information (creativity) in a small space, they are judged differently than taking a sentence from a copyrighted work.
If you are the original author, then it should be possible to get permission for reuse of the original. In fact, you may already have a license for some uses from when you turned over copyright. And "as much as possible" is a judgement call. In this case it may not be possible.
And, citation is, of course, required.
Do the right thing. (Mookie, from the movie with the same name)

I don't really understand this answer. Assuming this concerns a table of (numerical) data, the suggested cosmetic changes are indeed inessential to the information, but they are also likely to address precisely the elements protected under copyright law in many jurisdictions. The text of a novel is quite different from the data in such a table, being a quintessential creative work.

My understanding is that the data is inessential to the copyright (though it is both numerical and text), but should naturally be cited properly. The copyright transfer allows me to reproduce e.g. tables in work that I publish, but not that someone else does.
